# Center align ellipsis in string with line limit

Tags: css, reactjs, truncate

I am trying to align the ellipsis into the center of the string (middle truncation) if the string is longer than 2 lines. Right now I have the ellipsis at the end like so `this is a test string that could be longer than 2 lines...`. What I am trying to accomplish is something like this `this is a test string that ... could be longer than 2 lines`. I have seen where you can do it based off of character length, but that makes it hard for all breakpoints down to mobile.

This is how I am currently accomplishing adding the ellipsis to the end of the string and limiting it to 2 lines

```
#limitTwoLines {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
  line-clamp: 2;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}
```